# IWebBrowser2, OnBeforeNavigate2, about:

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, url, iwebbrowser2

i have problems in handling a simple html-link with the IWebBrowser2-Interface.

Image i navigate to an url like that

**scheme://host:port/path.html**

The file **path.html** contains html/javascript code that automatically links to another html file, that is located in an url like this

**scheme://host:port/target.html**

The first file is loaded fine. But once the IE handles the link from **path.html** the value of the url, which is passed as a parameter to the OnBeforeNavigate2-Handler contains a strange value looking like this

**"about:target.html"**

There is indeed the name of the file, that **path.html** linked to, but the whole
remaining part of the url is lost.

Does anybody has an idea how this inconvenience could be resolved?

Thanks in advance.